# How to test database record with different time zone?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, testing, rspec

Now I am developing a rails project.
My database is MySQL.

I check my MySQL's timezone:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

And the `SYSTEM` timezone is:

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP))) AS `timezone`;
+----------+
| timezone |
+----------+
|        9 |
+----------+
```

Also, my linux system's timezone is:

```
$ date +'%:z %Z'
+09:00 JST
```

Now, when I insert a record to database, the created_at value will be utc time. For example:

```
# Now is 14:25:59
Product.create(name: 'Best')
# select created_at from products;
# 5:25:59
```

So if I test the feature with rspec in my spec source, I should get that data from database and plus 9 to equal the current system time. Is it good?

Why the data been saved as a utc time with active_record? If use this configuration, is there a way to test the database record in a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (maybe) best approach is to save all at UTC-Time. So Then you can use the Time.in_time_zone to get the time inside a specified zone.

My 20:00 PM is UTC 13:00 and maybe your 06:00 AM - but in the database its just the same time - UTC.

If it then comes to Rendering you use the rails helper for timing and always give the `created_at.in_time_zone`.

If it comes to rendering you just throw out the UTC timestamp and let JavaScript to the rest, formatting the timestamp to the users local time.

Comment: Thank you. You told me a good way -- `in_time_zone`. I used it and it worked well.